# Can you overload the Python 3.6 f-string's "operator"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, f-string

In Python 3.6, you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) like:

```
>>> date = datetime.date(1991, 10, 12)
>>> f'{date} was on a {date:%A}'
'1991-10-12 was on a Saturday'
```

I want to overload the method receiving the `'%A'` above. Can it be done?

For example, if I wanted to write a dumb wrapper around `datetime`, I might expect this overloading to look something like:

```
class MyDatetime:
    def __init__(self, my_datetime, some_other_value):
        self.dt = my_datetime
        self.some_other_value = some_other_value

    def __fstr__(self, format_str):
        return (
            self.dt.strftime(format_str) + 
            'some other string' +
            str(self.some_other_value
        )
```

Comment: [Here's one I prepared earlier](https://gist.github.com/wimglenn/3186645d0474550160d3210bf488f8f8).

Comment: for some more flexibility, you can override the methods made available in the [`string.Formatter` class](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.Formatter) - such as `get_field`, `get_value`, `check_unused_args`, `format_field`, and `convert_field` - to get some more detailed control over the `format` function behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Yes*, but by using `__format__`, not `__fstr__`.

---

`f`-strings were not an overhaul of the previous methods to format strings. Instead, it built on the protocols already in place.

From [PEP 0498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498) that introduced them, in [Code equivalence](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#code-equivalence):

> The exact code used to implement f-strings is not specified. However, it is guaranteed that any embedded value that is converted to a string will use that value's `__format__` method. This is the same mechanism that `str.format()` uses to convert values to strings.

and then again, in [Format Specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#format-specifiers):

> Once expressions in a format specifier are evaluated (if necessary), format specifiers are not interpreted by the f-string evaluator. Just as in `str.format()`, they are merely passed in to the `__format__()` method of the object being formatted.

So, there's no *new* special method for them. You need to define a `__format__` method that takes the spec and returns an appropriately formatted string.

As the docs on [`__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) also describe:

> Called by the `format()` built-in function, and by extension, *evaluation of formatted string literals* and the `str.format()` method, to produce a “formatted” string representation of an object.