What is a simple way to round all floats in an f-string to the same number of digits in one step?
I have a long f-string with containing many float values, all of which I want to round to the same number of digits. Is there a way to do this in one go or in a smart way, or do I need to specify the digits at for each one separately?
I know that I can round a value in an f-string using
print(f"pi rounded to 2 decimals is {math.pi:.2f}")

However, I would like to do something along the lines of:
print(f"rounding pi and tau and e to 2 digits results in {math.pi}, {math.tau}, {math.e}, respectively:"<some operation to round all to two digits.>)

(This is a minimal example. In reality, my string has many more floats associated to it (and isn't just a list of mathematical constants)).
I know I can could do something like:
constants = [math.pi, math.tau, math.e]
rounded_constants = [str(round(c, 2)) for c in constants]
print(f"rounding pi and tau and e to 2 digits results in {rounded_constants[0]}, {rounded_constants[1]}, {rounded_constants[2]}, respectively"

but this seems a bit roundabout to me and I was wondering if there's a more direct way to do it.
(EDITED: I edited the question to clarify that I don't really care about doing it in a single step, but just want to find a smarter way than specifying it for each float separately)

No, there's no way I know of to specify a "default formatting" with f-strings.

You may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876683/hook-into-the-builtin-python-f-string-format-machinery - not an exact dupe, but very close.

I'm don't think there's a built-in way to do it but you can use the .replace method combined with the .format method to avoid repeating the :.2f
print('rounding constants: {}, {}, {}'.replace('{}','{:.2f}').format(math.pi, math.e, math.tau))


You can even expand on this to define a "custom format specifier": "{:mf} {:mf} {:mf}".replace("{:mf}", "{:.2f}").format(...)

There is no default formatting, but you can use re.sub on the string
s = f"rounding pi and tau and e to 2 digits results in {math.pi}, {math.tau}, {math.e}, respectively:"
s = re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+', lambda x: f"{float(x.group()):.2f}", s)

Outoput
rounding pi and tau and e to 2 digits results in 3.14, 6.28, 2.72, respectively:


You can use str.format() to good effect here as follows:
import math

constants = [math.pi, math.tau, math.e]

result = "pi={} tau={} e={}".format(*map(lambda x: f"{x:.2f}", constants))

print(result)

Output:
pi=3.14 tau=6.28 e=2.72

Doing it this way means that you only have one place (the lambda) where you specify the formatting
