# Extend Formatter features to f-string syntax

Tags: python, f-string

In a project of mine, I'm passing strings to a Formatter subclass whic formats it using the [format specifier mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). In my case it is customized (using the features of the Formatter class) by adding additional bang converters : !u converts the resulting string to lowercase, !c to titlecase, !q doubles any square bracket (because reasons), and some others.

For example, using `a = "toFu"`, `"{a!c}"` becomes `"Tofu"`

How could I make my system use f-string **syntax**, so I can have `"{a+a!c}"` be turned into `"Tofutofu"` ?

NB: I'm not asking for a way of making `f"{a+a!c}"` (note the presence of an `f`) resolve itself as `"Tofutofu"`, which is what [hook into the builtin python f-string format machinery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876683/hook-into-the-builtin-python-f-string-format-machinery) covers, I'm asking if there is a way for a function or any form of python code to turn `"{a+a!c}"` (note the absence of an `f`) into `"Tofutofu"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hook into the builtin python f-string format machinery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876683/hook-into-the-builtin-python-f-string-format-machinery). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081521/can-you-overload-the-python-3-6-f-strings-operator

Comment: You can't add your own `!`-magic, but you can control how an _object_ is formatted with some modifiers after `:`, like `x = 42069; print(f"{x:_}")`. See [this article by nedbat](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/python_custom_formatting.html)

Comment: I reopened your question because I feel I'm not expert enough to judge in this field. But I have to say your last edit confused me even more: you want to change the way Python parses regular strings? i.e. to enforce format specifiers on simple string literals, without `f`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I'm asking how it would be possible for a **function** (or for some sort of python code, as I said) to take the string with brackets, and return the one with titlecased tofu.

Comment: Could be done using regex I guess... Will the `!x` always be at the end of the `{...}`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I'm not sure, I think there could be spaces after it. But even that aside, what would you seek with the regex:  the `!x`, or the value to interpolate ? If the former, it's probably not that hard to do, but what do I do next ? If the latter, how would a regex capture the insane complexity of, for example, the `=` which can be included in f-string interpolations (even more in a forward-compatible way) ?

Comment: Yep this sounds like a complex and interesting problem, maybe far more than I can still grasp it. Anyway, this is why I reopened it - hopefully someone can better help, and I posted an answer with what I could understand. Who knows, might even be a starting ground for someone to get to the answer you need... Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evolved from @Tomerikoo 's life-saving answer, here's the code:

```py
import re

def formatter(s):
    def replacement(match):
        pre, bangs, suf = match.group(1, 2, 3)
        # pre : the part before the first bang
        # bangs : the bang (if any) and the characters going with it
        # suf : the colon (if any) and the characters going with it

        if not bangs:
            return eval("f\"{" + pre + suf + "}\"")

        conversion = set(bangs[1:]) # the first character is always a bang
        sra = conversion - set("tiqulc")
        conversion = conversion - sra
        if sra:
            sra = "!" + "".join(sra)

        value = eval("f\"{" + pre + (sra or "") + suf + "}\"")

        if "q" in conversion:
            value = value.replace("{", "{{")

        if "u" in conversion:
            value = value.upper()

        if "l" in conversion:
            value = value.lower()

        if "c" in conversion and value:
            value = value.capitalize()

        return value

    return re.sub(r"{([^!:\n]+)((?:![^!:\n]+)?)((?::[^!:\n]+)?)}", replacement, s)
```

The massive regex results in the three groups I commented about at the top.

Caveat: it still uses eval (no acceptable way around it anyway), it doesn't allow for multiline replacement fields, and it may cause issues and/or discrepancies to put spaces between the `!` and the `:`.
But these are acceptable for the use I have.

Comment: I'm so happy to see my silly code helped you get to a solution in the end ^_^

Comment: Regarding your last issue, I'm might not fully understand (again...) but I think if you just add a `\s*` between the `!` part and the `:` part it will be solved. i.e. something like `{a!c  :s}` would work (maybe the `+` of the `!` part needs to be lazy - `+?`)

Comment: @Tomerikoo maybe add the `\s*` rather between the `?:` of the last group and the `:` just after it ? Or inside the last capturing group, but outside of the last non-capturing group ? That way it's captured in the last group, which I'm just passing through unchanged... I'll check that tonight if I keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I still fully understand what you need, but from the details given in the question and some comments, here is a function that parses strings with the format you specified and gives the desired results:

```py
import re

def formatter(s):
    def replacement(match):
        expr, frmt = match[1].split('!')
        if frmt == 'c':
            return eval(expr).title()

    return re.sub(r"{([^{]+)}", replacement, s)

a = "toFu"
print(formatter("blah {a!c}"))
print(formatter("{a+a!c}blah"))
```

Outputs:

```
blah Tofu
Tofutofublah
```

This uses the function variation of the `repl` argument of the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function. This function (`replacement`) can be further extended to support all other `!x`s.

Main disadvantages:

- Using `eval` is evil.
- This doesn't take in count regular format specifiers, i.e. `:0.3`

Maybe someone can take it from here and improve.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll take it from here, I think I can make it work. I'll post here if I end up with something workable.

Answer (score -2):

Please check specifcation
only those characters are allowed : 's', 'r', or 'a'

https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/

Comment: The OP specifically said they are adding their own customized converters. The question is how (or if possible) to add them to the f-strings syntax